# NSIS uninstaller RMDir from appdata folder

Tags: nsis

is there a way to delete files from the c:\users{username}\appdata\local folder? is there a predefined variable for this? Win 7 stores some information in there from my app and i would like to delete theses files upon uninstall.

I know there is a predefined $APPDATA variable but it goes to \roaming not \local

is there a  predifeined variable for c:\users{username}\  ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This path and many others is defined in *constants* (look at the 4.2.3 section of the [Chapter 4](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html) of the manual).

I think you are looking for the `$LOCALAPPDATA` value that states it is "The local (nonroaming) application data directory".

Remember that you can choose between your account and all users folders resolution of the path constants with the `SetShellVarContext` command.